# readystatechange event of XMLHttpRequest fires before end of current script

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the following code, line (a) will trigger the event 'readystatechange' and log this.readyState to the console BEFORE logging "ends" at line (b). I am wondering why this happens. Should the callback be put at the event queue and will only be executed after the main script finishes?

```
    const somePath = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange';
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(xhr.readyState); // will output 0
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        console.log(this.readyState)
    }); 
    xhr.open('GET', somePath, true); // (a) will output 1 to console
    console.log('ends'); // (b)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not just ignore or return if `readyState` is `1`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Just want to learn more about how events work in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is that events (in this context, at least) are called *synchronously*, rather than asynchronously. It's not that a function call gets added to the end of the queue - it's that when `xhr.open` is run and the `readystatechange` event happens, code internal to the `xhr` will iterate through the attached listeners *synchronously* and execute them.

The code structure looks something similar to the following:

```js
const obj = (() => {
  const listeners = [];
  const addListener = fn => listeners.push(fn);
  const doSomething = () => {
    console.log('doing something');
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener());
  };
  return { addListener, doSomething };
})();
obj.addListener(() => console.log('listener running'));
obj.doSomething();
console.log('end of main thread');
```